# Migrating from short-term to long-term slot on Rococo

Tags: rococo, parachain-collator

We had a [temporary slot with para_id `3026`](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/357) previously and wanted to request for long-term slot (now that we have launched on Kusama) with the matching `2119`.

We thought the procedure is to:

- generate new chain spec with `"para_id": 2119`
- redeploy bootnode and collators
- update `para_id` on [polkadot-js/apps](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps)
- request for long-term slot on [paritytech/subport](https://github.com/paritytech/subport)

Our collators ran into this error after chain spec update:

```
Bootnode with peer id 12D.... is on a different chain (our genesis: ... theirs: ...)
```

Are we missing something or is there a different approach to this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your bootnodes are still running in the old version.

So, when the new nodes connect to the bootnodes, they will report 'different genesis'.

---

You could:

- stop 3026 and update all nodes to 2119
- remove the old bootnodes from your new spec file and add some new bootnodes

Comment: Yeah you're right. I had to `docker system prune` to make sure new chain spec is used. Also asked for recommendation here: https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/466